# Can we use netflix-eureka as external load balancer

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Can Eureka be used by outside world to discover my service? Below is the flow:

**Public client**( developed in any technology and not using Eureka) --> **Eureka server** (hosted on my organization server, exposed to outside world) --> My Eureka aware **services**.

I am trying to understand how Netfilx Eureka works from overall architecture point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Load Balancer and discovery service are two completely different things.

```
Discovery service = a registry of currently available services


Load Balancer = a routing of requests based on various rules
```

So, Eureka, as a discovery service, cannot be used a Load Balancer by itself.

However Eureka, being an application by itself, exposes an [HTTP REST API](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations)

So if you want to build a load balancer by yourself based on the information provided by eureka, you can call rest APIs like this.

For example, Ribbon, being a client side load balancer, calls these APIs internally.

Having said that, its not unclear why to use the tool for the purpose for which is not intended to be...

Comment: So, ideally Eureka should not be exposed to outside world? It should be used by public APIs to discover internal APIs, am I correct? If my statement is correct, then all my microservices will be used as internally API and I need to develop a different set for exposing it to public? ( Considering HTTP-REST-APIS are just an add-on feature to support another technologies apart from java).

Comment: Yes. Eureka should be internal registry. If you want a single "gate" you can use zuul or in spring 5 there is another spring solution that supports reactive stack...